# Out-of-order list iteration in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, iteration, fold

I'm implementing a (toy) stack machine in Haskell. I've defined a step function, `step :: State -> Instruction -> State`, which applies the result of a given instruction to a given state and returns the resultant state of the machine. Obviously, I'd like to have a function, `run :: State -> Program -> State` (where `Program :: [Instruction]`) that essentially calls `step` as many times as needed in order to execute the given input program.

My initial, naive solution was to `foldl`, like so:

```hs
run :: State -> Program -> State
run st prog = foldl (step) st prog
```

Obviously, this can't support jumps, which would modify *where abouts in the list I need to be*. All this implementation does is iterate left-to-right through the program. For additional context, the program's state, `State`, is as follows:

```hs
data State = State {
    pc :: Word,
    reg :: Word,
    stack :: [Word],
    memory :: [Word]
}
    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

and instructions are as follows:

```hs
data Opcode = Add | Sub | Mul | Div | Mod | Jump | Push | Pop | Load | Store | Set | Call | Ret | Pos | Dup | Swap | Halt | Nop
    deriving (Enum, Show, Eq)

data Instruction = Instruction {
    opcode :: Opcode,
    arg :: Maybe Word
}
    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

**How do I iterate through the list in an arbitrary order (and potentially forever, of course) so that I can support jumps**?

Comment: As a side note, you probably shouldn't call it `State` due to there already being a `State` type in Haskell's standard library.

Comment: This seems like a great time to use explicit recursion instead of relying on things like `foldl`. If the program shouldn't stop, then recurse with the result of the `step`, otherwise return the finished state. You may find that jumps are exceedingly slow due to the nature of linked lists, so this may be a good time to [look into arrays](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Array-IArray.html).

Comment: You have a `pc` yet you're using a fold -- this seems a little off, no?  If you want to use a pc, then you probably want something like a vector of instructions that you can index into rather than a list.  If you'd rather use the list, scrap the pc entirely and store the program in the `State`.  Here's the trick: store both the current execution (the list of instructions not yet run) and the "whole program".  Then, processing a `Jump` becomes possible.

Comment: @DDub that's the crux of the issue, yes. I need explicit recursion to enable "jumping around" per se, I've just had trouble formulating it. For what it's worth, I have an equivalent Rust implementation but it uses mutable state to track current location in program code.

Comment: @Aplet123 Thanks for the `State` warning -- I'm assuming Haskell manages this sanely with its module system? Otherwise I'll change the names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your `step` function will need to report whether it's time to halt or not. For example, let's suppose you modify its type to `step :: State -> Instruction -> Maybe State`. Then you can implement `run` just by shipping out to it:

```
run :: State -> Program -> State
run state prog = case step state (prog !! fromIntegral (pc state)) of
    Nothing -> state
    Just state' -> run state' prog
```

(You can avoid the `fromIntegral` by making your `pc` have type `Int` instead of `Word`.)

Note that `(!!)` is O(2<sup>n</sup>)<sup>*</sup> (fight me in the comments ;-). You should consider switching from `[Instruction]` to `Array Word Instruction` so that you can use `(!)` instead, which is O(n).

<sup>*</sup> Okay, to be precise, `(!!)` is technically O(1) because `Int` has a fixed size -- but, ohhhh, that constant factor! So let's say, a suitable generalization of `(!!)` to `Integer` is O(2<sup>n</sup>). Similar quibbles apply to `(!)`.

Comment: I guess `(+) @Integer` is also O(n), then :-P

Comment: @chi Yep! Now, if you work out what the best bound for `(*)` is, let me know...

Comment: I'd guess it's O(n*log n*log(log n)), "but its proof is too long to fit into this comment"™.

Comment: Marking this as the answer as it directly addresses the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Using an array is probably a good way to go, but there's also a way to step through your program that's a bit more like a fold by doing away with the program counter altogether.

The program counter is simply a pointer to the instruction in your program that you're going to run next.  So, instead of having a program counter, we can just put the instruction to run next right into the state.  Consider this alternate implementation of `State`:

```hs
data State = State
  { reg     :: Word
  , stack   :: [Word]
  , memory  :: [Word]
  , program :: Program
  } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Now we must reconsider `step`.  In particular, every time we `step`, we aren't increasing (or arbitrarily modifying) the `pc` but rather changing the program to be run.  Furthermore, we don't need to take an instruction as an argument because `State` already knows what is about to be run.  Thus, we have something like:

```hs
step :: State -> State
step st = case program st of
  []          -> st
  HALT : _    -> st {program = []}
  ADD  : rest -> st {program = rest, ...} -- Do whatever you do for add too
  ...
```

But, what do we do for `JUMP`?  How can we jump to an arbitrary position in the program when the program is disappearing on us as we run it?  One option is to additionally keep track of the original program.  We could put this in the `State` as another field, but for variety, I'm going to pass it as an additional argument to `step`, as in:

```hs
step :: Program -> State -> State
step originalProgram st = case program st of
  []         -> st
  HALT : _   -> st {program = []}
  JUMP n : _ -> st {program = drop n originalProgram}
  ...
```

(Note that here I'm assuming that your JUMP is absolute as opposed to relative.  If you have relative jumps, then instead of keeping track of the original program, you'd need to keep track of the "already executed" part of the program, probably as a list of instructions in reverse order.  That is, every time you execute an instruction, you would pop it off the `program` list and push it onto the `executed` list.  When you hit a JUMP that went backwards `n` instructions, you would just pop `n` off of the executed and push them back onto the program list.)

Now all that's left is to run the whole program:

```hs
run :: State -> Program -> State
run startState originalProgram = go (startState {program = originalProgram})
  where
    go st = case program st of
      [] -> st
      _  -> go $ step originalProgram st
```

As far as performance goes, this is certainly worse than using an array; most steps will be fast, but JUMPS may take longer.  On the other hand, you can run infinitely long programs this way, and you don't have to worry about indexes that are out of bounds.

Comment: I didn't think about redesigning it in such a way - this is very elegant.